# I'm having problems understanding why I keep getting NaN as a return output

Tags: javascript, function, dom

```js
const myFunction = function() {
   let fah;
   fah = document.getElementById('fah').value;

   let celcius;
   celcius = ((fah - 32) * 5/9);

  document.getElementById('cel').value = celcius;
};
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <h1 class="header">Fahrenhiet to celcius</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <form class="form">
        <div class="fah">
          <label for="fah" class="fahrenhiet" id="fah">&#176F</label>
          <input type="text" id="fah" class="input-fah" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="span">
          <span class="equals"> &#61 </span>
        </div>
        <div class="cel">
          <input type="text" id="cel" class="input-cel" value="">
          <label for="cel" class="celcius">&#176C</label>
        </div>
        <div class="bttn-group">
          <button class="bttn bttn-sumbit" type="" onclick="myFunction(); event.preventDefault();">Submit</button> 
          <input class="bttn bttn-reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I came back to this code after a week and it was working perfect before. Now all of a sudden every time I run it I keep getting NaN as my output. I've tried everything I can think of even using parseInt(), but after toying around I realize that my fah variable is not being treated as a number as far as I can tell. I tried deleting the document.getElementById('fah').value; and used a random number and it seemed to work. I'm at a loss. I'm still learning javascript so I'm sure it's something I haven't learned yet.

Comment: Did you try doing `console.log(document.getElementById("fah"))`?

Answer (score 3):

You had a duplicate ID in your HTML which is not valid and caused your code to pick up the `value` of the label instead of the input field.

You should also `parseInt` the user input to make sure it's a number.

```js
const myFunction = function() {
   let fah;
   fah = parseInt(document.getElementById('fah').value);
// CHANGE ---^

   let celcius;
   celcius = ((fah - 32) * 5/9);

  document.getElementById('cel').value = celcius;
};
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <h1 class="header">Fahrenhiet to celcius</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <form class="form">
        <div class="fah">
          <label for="fah" class="fahrenhiet" id="fah-label">&#176F</label>
<!-- CHANGE ---------------------------------------^ -->
          <input type="text" id="fah" class="input-fah" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="span">
          <span class="equals"> &#61 </span>
        </div>
        <div class="cel">
          <input type="text" id="cel" class="input-cel" value="">
          <label for="cel" class="celcius">&#176C</label>
        </div>
        <div class="bttn-group">
          <button class="bttn bttn-sumbit" type="" onclick="myFunction(); event.preventDefault();">Submit</button> 
          <input class="bttn bttn-reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The label doesn't even need an ID.

Comment: It doesn't but who knows what they use it for

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even realize the duplicate label. As soon as I fixed it everything works.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Feel free to mark this the answer @Randy for my imaginary internet points.